# How to fit child contents inside parent div even after zoom in

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I fit child div contents inside parent div. So that even if I zoom in the screen, the child div wont come out of parent div.

```
<div>
            <div title="childDiv"  style="width:auto;">
                <h3 class="headerwidth" style="margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:0px"> &nbsp;Test:</h3>
                Welcome to the this new page test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
</div>
```

I have tried overflow: hidden but does not work

Comment: give childDiv width 100%

Comment: I tried that but when I zoom in the child div comes out of parent

Comment: my child div comes out of parent if my zoom in size is 175 and plus

Comment: set the width of the parent div to 100% too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <div title="childDiv">
    <h3 class="headerwidth"> &nbsp;Test:</h3>
    <p>Welcome to the this new page test test test test test test test   test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope i understand what you ask.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: Basically what i need is child div width should be always remain inside parent div width...the child div should not come outside if i zoom in the page. Is there anyway we can do with bootstrap